# Fixing an error in plotting a gpx file using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm attempting to create a map showing a series of gpx files using ggplot2. Most of the gpx files work a treat, but some of them throw up some errors where what is plotted is a solid shape instead of a line. I've included one such example below. The plot in base R shows what the result should look like.

I'm not entirely sure what the source of the ggplot2 error is, any ideas would be much appreciated.

The gpx file used below can be downloaded (from Strava) [here] (a subset of the dataframe showing a less extreme version of the error) is pasted below[1](https://www.strava.com/activities/1347904490).

The code I'm using is:

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

gpxFile <- "file.gpx"
gpxRoute <- readOGR(dsn = gpxFile, layer = "tracks")

## PLOT USING BASE R

base_plot <- plot(gpxRoute)

## PLOT USING GGPLOT2

gg_plot <- gpxRoute %>%
  fortify() %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, colour = "red")) 
gg_plot
```

**Base R result**

[image: Plot using base R]
**ggplot result**

[image: Attempt using ggplot2]

```
long    lat order   piece   id  group
-83.709161  22.619206   1   1   0   0.1
-83.709266  22.619215   2   1   0   0.1
-83.709306  22.619246   3   1   0   0.1
-83.709326  22.619332   4   1   0   0.1
-83.70931   22.619351   5   1   0   0.1
-83.70928   22.619368   6   1   0   0.1
-83.709187  22.619423   7   1   0   0.1
-83.708963  22.61954    8   1   0   0.1
-83.708892  22.619578   9   1   0   0.1
-83.708747  22.619654   10  1   0   0.1
-83.70867   22.619691   11  1   0   0.1
-83.708626  22.619716   12  1   0   0.1
-83.70854   22.619751   13  1   0   0.1
-83.708441  22.619753   14  1   0   0.1
-83.708397  22.619734   15  1   0   0.1
-83.708322  22.619675   16  1   0   0.1
-83.708291  22.619636   17  1   0   0.1
-83.708225  22.619523   18  1   0   0.1
-83.707969  22.619138   19  1   0   0.1
-83.707798  22.618925   20  1   0   0.1
-83.707712  22.618808   21  1   0   0.1
-83.707538  22.618596   22  1   0   0.1
-83.707271  22.618281   23  1   0   0.1
-83.707116  22.618113   24  1   0   0.1
-83.70708   22.618067   25  1   0   0.1
-83.706976  22.617948   26  1   0   0.1
-83.706939  22.617891   27  1   0   0.1
-83.706936  22.617864   28  1   0   0.1
-83.70695   22.617832   29  1   0   0.1
-83.707005  22.617783   30  1   0   0.1
-83.707123  22.617706   31  1   0   0.1
-83.707189  22.61766    32  1   0   0.1
-83.707277  22.617599   33  1   0   0.1
-83.707458  22.617471   34  1   0   0.1
-83.707482  22.617453   35  1   0   0.1
-83.707715  22.617292   36  1   0   0.1
-83.707746  22.617274   37  1   0   0.1
-83.707911  22.617167   38  1   0   0.1
-83.707935  22.617149   39  1   0   0.1
-83.708135  22.617011   40  1   0   0.1
-83.708156  22.616995   41  1   0   0.1
-83.708371  22.616822   42  1   0   0.1
-83.708553  22.616694   43  1   0   0.1
-83.708776  22.616549   44  1   0   0.1
-83.708804  22.61653    45  1   0   0.1
-83.708968  22.616423   46  1   0   0.1
-83.709033  22.616374   47  1   0   0.1
-83.709138  22.616293   48  1   0   0.1
-83.709363  22.616137   49  1   0   0.1
-83.709538  22.61601    50  1   0   0.1
-83.709717  22.615881   51  1   0   0.1
-83.710095  22.615612   52  1   0   0.1
-83.71014   22.615576   53  1   0   0.1
-83.710229  22.615506   54  1   0   0.1
-83.710361  22.615418   55  1   0   0.1
-83.710483  22.615331   56  1   0   0.1
-83.710624  22.615228   57  1   0   0.1
-83.710839  22.615081   58  1   0   0.1
-83.711007  22.614961   59  1   0   0.1
-83.711066  22.61492    60  1   0   0.1
-83.711257  22.614781   61  1   0   0.1
-83.711387  22.614687   62  1   0   0.1
-83.711451  22.614643   63  1   0   0.1
-83.711802  22.614388   64  1   0   0.1
-83.712179  22.614133   65  1   0   0.1
-83.71261   22.613827   66  1   0   0.1
-83.712949  22.613592   67  1   0   0.1
-83.713258  22.613418   68  1   0   0.1
-83.713556  22.613264   69  1   0   0.1
-83.71398   22.613126   70  1   0   0.1
-83.714368  22.613104   71  1   0   0.1
-83.714846  22.613101   72  1   0   0.1
-83.715374  22.613075   73  1   0   0.1
-83.715969  22.612996   74  1   0   0.1
-83.716432  22.61291    75  1   0   0.1
-83.716665  22.612862   76  1   0   0.1
-83.716952  22.612805   77  1   0   0.1
-83.717541  22.612694   78  1   0   0.1
-83.71801   22.612598   79  1   0   0.1
-83.718123  22.612572   80  1   0   0.1
-83.718525  22.612503   81  1   0   0.1
-83.718725  22.612468   82  1   0   0.1
-83.718849  22.612446   83  1   0   0.1
-83.718888  22.612439   84  1   0   0.1
-83.71909   22.6124 85  1   0   0.1
-83.719118  22.612393   86  1   0   0.1
-83.719291  22.61235    87  1   0   0.1
-83.719351  22.612337   88  1   0   0.1
-83.719506  22.612314   89  1   0   0.1
-83.719567  22.612303   90  1   0   0.1
-83.719819  22.612253   91  1   0   0.1
-83.71995   22.612231   92  1   0   0.1
-83.720288  22.612167   93  1   0   0.1
-83.720704  22.612091   94  1   0   0.1
-83.72081   22.612072   95  1   0   0.1
-83.721106  22.61201    96  1   0   0.1
-83.72145   22.611942   97  1   0   0.1
-83.721593  22.611914   98  1   0   0.1
-83.722119  22.611818   99  1   0   0.1
-83.722405  22.611766   100 1   0   0.1
-83.722557  22.611739   101 1   0   0.1
-83.723005  22.61165    102 1   0   0.1
-83.723457  22.611564   103 1   0   0.1
-83.723606  22.611533   104 1   0   0.1
-83.723959  22.611457   105 1   0   0.1
-83.724322  22.611388   106 1   0   0.1
-83.724781  22.611302   107 1   0   0.1
-83.725287  22.611207   108 1   0   0.1
-83.725396  22.611187   109 1   0   0.1
-83.725812  22.611107   110 1   0   0.1
-83.726339  22.611001   111 1   0   0.1
-83.726939  22.610882   112 1   0   0.1
-83.727055  22.610859   113 1   0   0.1
-83.727628  22.61075    114 1   0   0.1
-83.727792  22.610717   115 1   0   0.1
-83.727899  22.610695   116 1   0   0.1
-83.728255  22.610629   117 1   0   0.1
-83.728406  22.610605   118 1   0   0.1
-83.728722  22.61055    119 1   0   0.1
-83.729309  22.610428   120 1   0   0.1
-83.729845  22.610325   121 1   0   0.1
-83.730203  22.610257   122 1   0   0.1
-83.730558  22.610183   123 1   0   0.1
-83.730822  22.610136   124 1   0   0.1
-83.731366  22.61003    125 1   0   0.1
-83.731729  22.609965   126 1   0   0.1
-83.732297  22.609857   127 1   0   0.1
-83.732653  22.609779   128 1   0   0.1
-83.732887  22.609733   129 1   0   0.1
-83.732972  22.609723   130 1   0   0.1
-83.733337  22.609653   131 1   0   0.1
-83.733799  22.609563   132 1   0   0.1
-83.734275  22.609466   133 1   0   0.1
-83.734796  22.609369   134 1   0   0.1
-83.735091  22.609308   135 1   0   0.1
-83.735136  22.609301   136 1   0   0.1
-83.735265  22.609282   137 1   0   0.1
-83.735326  22.609278   138 1   0   0.1
-83.73534   22.609287   139 1   0   0.1
-83.735308  22.609324   140 1   0   0.1
-83.735284  22.609359   141 1   0   0.1
-83.735222  22.60951    142 1   0   0.1
-83.735251  22.609714   143 1   0   0.1
-83.735263  22.609797   144 1   0   0.1
-83.735276  22.609971   145 1   0   0.1
-83.735271  22.610167   146 1   0   0.1
-83.73525   22.6104 147 1   0   0.1
-83.735234  22.610513   148 1   0   0.1
-83.735187  22.610721   149 1   0   0.1
-83.735164  22.610863   150 1   0   0.1
-83.735085  22.611153   151 1   0   0.1
-83.73503   22.61135    152 1   0   0.1
-83.734956  22.6116 153 1   0   0.1
-83.734906  22.611762   154 1   0   0.1
-83.734832  22.611991   155 1   0   0.1
-83.734737  22.612312   156 1   0   0.1
-83.734713  22.61238    157 1   0   0.1
-83.734674  22.612521   158 1   0   0.1
-83.734591  22.612813   159 1   0   0.1
-83.73452   22.61304    160 1   0   0.1
-83.734452  22.613273   161 1   0   0.1
-83.734377  22.613582   162 1   0   0.1
-83.734318  22.61381    163 1   0   0.1
-83.734292  22.613957   164 1   0   0.1
-83.73429   22.6141 165 1   0   0.1
-83.734309  22.614234   166 1   0   0.1
-83.734359  22.614411   167 1   0   0.1
-83.734464  22.614736   168 1   0   0.1
-83.734507  22.614834   169 1   0   0.1
-83.734627  22.615103   170 1   0   0.1
-83.734706  22.615283   171 1   0   0.1
-83.734798  22.615456   172 1   0   0.1
-83.734843  22.615539   173 1   0   0.1
-83.73498   22.61578    174 1   0   0.1
-83.735038  22.615856   175 1   0   0.1
-83.735215  22.616109   176 1   0   0.1
-83.735248  22.616154   177 1   0   0.1
-83.735389  22.616343   178 1   0   0.1
-83.735505  22.616493   179 1   0   0.1
-83.735546  22.616544   180 1   0   0.1
-83.735825  22.616842   181 1   0   0.1
-83.735868  22.616894   182 1   0   0.1
-83.736181  22.617301   183 1   0   0.1
-83.736214  22.617348   184 1   0   0.1
-83.736316  22.617533   185 1   0   0.1
-83.736471  22.617841   186 1   0   0.1
-83.736482  22.617877   187 1   0   0.1
-83.73658   22.61808    188 1   0   0.1
-83.736628  22.618179   189 1   0   0.1
-83.736714  22.618337   190 1   0   0.1
-83.736864  22.618575   191 1   0   0.1
-83.737055  22.618796   192 1   0   0.1
-83.737221  22.618952   193 1   0   0.1
-83.7373    22.619023   194 1   0   0.1
-83.737427  22.61916    195 1   0   0.1
-83.737478  22.619208   196 1   0   0.1
-83.737537  22.619251   197 1   0   0.1
-83.737602  22.619285   198 1   0   0.1
-83.737749  22.61931    199 1   0   0.1
-83.737822  22.619294   200 1   0   0.1
-83.737957  22.619251   201 1   0   0.1
-83.738281  22.619105   202 1   0   0.1
-83.73857   22.618979   203 1   0   0.1
-83.738742  22.618891   204 1   0   0.1
-83.738787  22.618871   205 1   0   0.1
-83.738853  22.618828   206 1   0   0.1
-83.738947  22.618781   207 1   0   0.1
-83.739011  22.618764   208 1   0   0.1
-83.739061  22.618742   209 1   0   0.1
-83.739144  22.618659   210 1   0   0.1
-83.739163  22.618642   211 1   0   0.1
-83.739248  22.618589   212 1   0   0.1
-83.739348  22.618564   213 1   0   0.1
-83.739471  22.618515   214 1   0   0.1
-83.739677  22.618463   215 1   0   0.1
-83.739808  22.618446   216 1   0   0.1
-83.739911  22.61845    217 1   0   0.1
-83.740005  22.618457   218 1   0   0.1
-83.740067  22.618472   219 1   0   0.1
-83.740059  22.618496   220 1   0   0.1
-83.739973  22.618493   221 1   0   0.1
-83.739825  22.618469   222 1   0   0.1
-83.739788  22.618466   223 1   0   0.1
-83.739684  22.618461   224 1   0   0.1
-83.739511  22.618476   225 1   0   0.1
-83.739444  22.618495   226 1   0   0.1
-83.739205  22.618599   227 1   0   0.1
-83.738841  22.618799   228 1   0   0.1
-83.738668  22.618898   229 1   0   0.1
-83.738514  22.618974   230 1   0   0.1
-83.738464  22.619013   231 1   0   0.1
-83.738424  22.619043   232 1   0   0.1
-83.738395  22.619061   233 1   0   0.1
-83.738284  22.619123   234 1   0   0.1
-83.738265  22.61913    235 1   0   0.1
-83.738159  22.619189   236 1   0   0.1
-83.737987  22.619272   237 1   0   0.1
-83.737766  22.619342   238 1   0   0.1
-83.737614  22.619325   239 1   0   0.1
-83.737487  22.619236   240 1   0   0.1
-83.7374    22.619133   241 1   0   0.1
-83.737379  22.619115   242 1   0   0.1
-83.737267  22.619004   243 1   0   0.1
-83.737097  22.618813   244 1   0   0.1
-83.737078  22.618794   245 1   0   0.1
-83.736933  22.618631   246 1   0   0.1
-83.736789  22.618421   247 1   0   0.1
-83.736614  22.61809    248 1   0   0.1
-83.73647   22.617792   249 1   0   0.1
-83.736445  22.617745   250 1   0   0.1
-83.736321  22.617507   251 1   0   0.1
-83.736209  22.617334   252 1   0   0.1
-83.735878  22.616923   253 1   0   0.1
-83.735591  22.616589   254 1   0   0.1
-83.73553   22.61652    255 1   0   0.1
-83.735349  22.616278   256 1   0   0.1
-83.735324  22.616245   257 1   0   0.1
-83.735164  22.616023   258 1   0   0.1
-83.735141  22.615992   259 1   0   0.1
-83.73496   22.615717   260 1   0   0.1
-83.734773  22.615392   261 1   0   0.1
-83.734602  22.615017   262 1   0   0.1
-83.734459  22.614668   263 1   0   0.1
-83.734446  22.614621   264 1   0   0.1
-83.734348  22.614326   265 1   0   0.1
-83.734308  22.613949   266 1   0   0.1
-83.734311  22.613895   267 1   0   0.1
-83.734399  22.613535   268 1   0   0.1
-83.734511  22.613182   269 1   0   0.1
-83.734584  22.61295    270 1   0   0.1
-83.734616  22.612842   271 1   0   0.1
-83.734702  22.612607   272 1   0   0.1
-83.734728  22.612534   273 1   0   0.1
-83.734736  22.612467   274 1   0   0.1
-83.734755  22.612378   275 1   0   0.1
-83.73481   22.612197   276 1   0   0.1
-83.734864  22.612037   277 1   0   0.1
-83.734911  22.611885   278 1   0   0.1
-83.734952  22.611754   279 1   0   0.1
-83.734998  22.611584   280 1   0   0.1
-83.735051  22.611412   281 1   0   0.1
-83.735123  22.611123   282 1   0   0.1
-83.735154  22.611009   283 1   0   0.1
-83.735229  22.610669   284 1   0   0.1
-83.735255  22.610522   285 1   0   0.1
-83.735291  22.61028    286 1   0   0.1
-83.735303  22.610137   287 1   0   0.1
-83.735302  22.609903   288 1   0   0.1
-83.735271  22.609513   289 1   0   0.1
-83.735259  22.60943    290 1   0   0.1
-83.735262  22.609368   291 1   0   0.1
-83.735334  22.609273   292 1   0   0.1
-83.735504  22.609238   293 1   0   0.1
-83.735884  22.609167   294 1   0   0.1
-83.736285  22.60909    295 1   0   0.1
-83.736699  22.609015   296 1   0   0.1
-83.737168  22.608971   297 1   0   0.1
-83.737219  22.608971   298 1   0   0.1
-83.73748   22.608968   299 1   0   0.1
-83.737953  22.608977   300 1   0   0.1
-83.73858   22.609001   301 1   0   0.1
-83.738633  22.609002   302 1   0   0.1
-83.738687  22.608998   303 1   0   0.1
-83.738895  22.609009   304 1   0   0.1
-83.739042  22.609014   305 1   0   0.1
-83.739288  22.609023   306 1   0   0.1
-83.739738  22.609048   307 1   0   0.1
-83.740238  22.60907    308 1   0   0.1
-83.74041   22.609076   309 1   0   0.1
-83.740791  22.609082   310 1   0   0.1
-83.741228  22.609102   311 1   0   0.1
-83.741286  22.609107   312 1   0   0.1
-83.741703  22.609118   313 1   0   0.1
-83.742255  22.60914    314 1   0   0.1
-83.742438  22.609148   315 1   0   0.1
-83.742567  22.609169   316 1   0   0.1
-83.742711  22.609181   317 1   0   0.1
-83.742773  22.609173   318 1   0   0.1
-83.742765  22.609147   319 1   0   0.1
-83.742702  22.609144   320 1   0   0.1
-83.742676  22.609144   321 1   0   0.1
-83.742605  22.609185   322 1   0   0.1
-83.7426    22.609189   323 1   0   0.1
-83.742617  22.609192   324 1   0   0.1
-83.742679  22.609184   325 1   0   0.1
-83.742925  22.609185   326 1   0   0.1
-83.743215  22.609196   327 1   0   0.1
-83.743604  22.60922    328 1   0   0.1
-83.743716  22.609232   329 1   0   0.1
-83.743951  22.609254   330 1   0   0.1
-83.744129  22.609267   331 1   0   0.1
-83.744322  22.609285   332 1   0   0.1
-83.744389  22.609288   333 1   0   0.1
-83.744598  22.609309   334 1   0   0.1
-83.744817  22.609326   335 1   0   0.1
-83.744891  22.609332   336 1   0   0.1
-83.745197  22.609355   337 1   0   0.1
-83.745506  22.609384   338 1   0   0.1
-83.745891  22.609411   339 1   0   0.1
-83.745966  22.609416   340 1   0   0.1
-83.746465  22.60945    341 1   0   0.1
-83.747062  22.609504   342 1   0   0.1
-83.747188  22.609514   343 1   0   0.1
-83.747807  22.609569   344 1   0   0.1
-83.748414  22.609623   345 1   0   0.1
-83.748533  22.609637   346 1   0   0.1
-83.749051  22.609693   347 1   0   0.1
-83.749634  22.609742   348 1   0   0.1
-83.749752  22.609754   349 1   0   0.1
-83.75034   22.609797   350 1   0   0.1
-83.75046   22.609801   351 1   0   0.1
-83.751027  22.60977    352 1   0   0.1
-83.751191  22.609746   353 1   0   0.1
-83.751511  22.609677   354 1   0   0.1
-83.751913  22.609556   355 1   0   0.1
-83.752321  22.609376   356 1   0   0.1
-83.752534  22.609281   357 1   0   0.1
-83.752703  22.609201   358 1   0   0.1
-83.753108  22.609009   359 1   0   0.1
-83.753453  22.608841   360 1   0   0.1
-83.753803  22.608683   361 1   0   0.1
-83.754121  22.608534   362 1   0   0.1
-83.754318  22.608426   363 1   0   0.1
-83.754403  22.60839    364 1   0   0.1
-83.754879  22.608192   365 1   0   0.1
-83.755255  22.608026   366 1   0   0.1
-83.755784  22.607805   367 1   0   0.1
-83.756137  22.607634   368 1   0   0.1
-83.756388  22.607508   369 1   0   0.1
-83.756613  22.607411   370 1   0   0.1
-83.756653  22.607395   371 1   0   0.1
-83.757037  22.607232   372 1   0   0.1
-83.757246  22.607142   373 1   0   0.1
-83.757343  22.607095   374 1   0   0.1
-83.757466  22.607038   375 1   0   0.1
-83.757647  22.606951   376 1   0   0.1
-83.757676  22.606936   377 1   0   0.1
-83.757816  22.60687    378 1   0   0.1
-83.75787   22.606845   379 1   0   0.1
-83.757968  22.606798   380 1   0   0.1
-83.758039  22.606765   381 1   0   0.1
-83.758153  22.606708   382 1   0   0.1
-83.758221  22.606681   383 1   0   0.1
-83.758265  22.606661   384 1   0   0.1
-83.758401  22.606606   385 1   0   0.1
-83.758445  22.606585   386 1   0   0.1
-83.758532  22.606549   387 1   0   0.1
-83.758681  22.606484   388 1   0   0.1
-83.758701  22.606473   389 1   0   0.1
-83.758873  22.606399   390 1   0   0.1
-83.758896  22.60639    391 1   0   0.1
-83.759005  22.606338   392 1   0   0.1
-83.75911   22.606289   393 1   0   0.1
-83.759131  22.606278   394 1   0   0.1
-83.759265  22.606212   395 1   0   0.1
-83.759353  22.606177   396 1   0   0.1
-83.759416  22.60615    397 1   0   0.1
-83.759546  22.606091   398 1   0   0.1
-83.759585  22.606074   399 1   0   0.1
-83.759715  22.606021   400 1   0   0.1
-83.75976   22.606005   401 1   0   0.1
-83.759825  22.605977   402 1   0   0.1
-83.759962  22.605939   403 1   0   0.1
-83.759985  22.605932   404 1   0   0.1
-83.760083  22.605913   405 1   0   0.1
-83.760202  22.605879   406 1   0   0.1
-83.760272  22.605857   407 1   0   0.1
-83.760394  22.605851   408 1   0   0.1
-83.760444  22.605847   409 1   0   0.1
-83.760624  22.605844   410 1   0   0.1
-83.760651  22.605842   411 1   0   0.1
-83.760817  22.605842   412 1   0   0.1
-83.760956  22.605851   413 1   0   0.1
-83.76104   22.605857   414 1   0   0.1
-83.761244  22.605878   415 1   0   0.1
-83.761302  22.605888   416 1   0   0.1
-83.761543  22.605928   417 1   0   0.1
-83.761603  22.605938   418 1   0   0.1
-83.761848  22.605978   419 1   0   0.1
-83.762129  22.606034   420 1   0   0.1
-83.76254   22.606101   421 1   0   0.1
-83.762905  22.606116   422 1   0   0.1
-83.762962  22.606114   423 1   0   0.1
-83.763148  22.606099   424 1   0   0.1
-83.76328   22.606078   425 1   0   0.1
-83.763393  22.60605    426 1   0   0.1
-83.763506  22.606022   427 1   0   0.1
-83.763556  22.606009   428 1   0   0.1
-83.76368   22.605977   429 1   0   0.1
-83.76374   22.605957   430 1   0   0.1
-83.763789  22.605946   431 1   0   0.1
-83.763816  22.6059 432 1   0   0.1
-83.76387   22.605841   433 1   0   0.1
-83.763963  22.605802   434 1   0   0.1
-83.76408   22.605761   435 1   0   0.1
-83.764208  22.605707   436 1   0   0.1
-83.764354  22.605645   437 1   0   0.1
-83.764435  22.605615   438 1   0   0.1
-83.764516  22.605583   439 1   0   0.1
-83.764683  22.605511   440 1   0   0.1
-83.76486   22.605437   441 1   0   0.1
-83.76495   22.605398   442 1   0   0.1
-83.765132  22.605321   443 1   0   0.1
-83.765494  22.605167   444 1   0   0.1
-83.765757  22.605058   445 1   0   0.1
-83.766234  22.604865   446 1   0   0.1
-83.7667    22.604651   447 1   0   0.1
-83.767082  22.604473   448 1   0   0.1
-83.767549  22.604282   449 1   0   0.1
-83.768037  22.604074   450 1   0   0.1
-83.768537  22.603843   451 1   0   0.1
-83.768821  22.603729   452 1   0   0.1
-83.768912  22.603689   453 1   0   0.1
-83.769131  22.603589   454 1   0   0.1
-83.769327  22.603497   455 1   0   0.1
-83.7694    22.603468   456 1   0   0.1
-83.76957   22.60339    457 1   0   0.1
-83.769603  22.603375   458 1   0   0.1
-83.769815  22.603269   459 1   0   0.1
-83.770022  22.603151   460 1   0   0.1
-83.770235  22.603008   461 1   0   0.1
-83.77026   22.602989   462 1   0   0.1
-83.770488  22.602784   463 1   0   0.1
-83.770537  22.602734   464 1   0   0.1
-83.770747  22.602537   465 1   0   0.1
-83.770822  22.602467   466 1   0   0.1
-83.770976  22.602329   467 1   0   0.1
-83.771139  22.602162   468 1   0   0.1
-83.771165  22.602138   469 1   0   0.1
-83.771425  22.601891   470 1   0   0.1
-83.771505  22.601815   471 1   0   0.1
-83.77179   22.601536   472 1   0   0.1
-83.771817  22.601511   473 1   0   0.1
-83.772057  22.60128    474 1   0   0.1
-83.772361  22.601011   475 1   0   0.1
-83.772416  22.600964   476 1   0   0.1
-83.772647  22.600784   477 1   0   0.1
-83.772706  22.60074    478 1   0   0.1
-83.772913  22.600601   479 1   0   0.1
-83.773004  22.600549   480 1   0   0.1
-83.773119  22.600475   481 1   0   0.1
-83.773224  22.600406   482 1   0   0.1
-83.773249  22.600386   483 1   0   0.1
-83.773415  22.600273   484 1   0   0.1
-83.773438  22.600258   485 1   0   0.1
-83.773558  22.600186   486 1   0   0.1
-83.773634  22.600141   487 1   0   0.1
-83.773756  22.600066   488 1   0   0.1
-83.773898  22.599973   489 1   0   0.1
-83.773923  22.599957   490 1   0   0.1
-83.77404   22.599877   491 1   0   0.1
-83.774134  22.599819   492 1   0   0.1
-83.774176  22.599785   493 1   0   0.1
-83.77432   22.599693   494 1   0   0.1
-83.774527  22.599564   495 1   0   0.1
-83.774616  22.599505   496 1   0   0.1
-83.774681  22.599458   497 1   0   0.1
-83.774819  22.599363   498 1   0   0.1
-83.774841  22.599348   499 1   0   0.1
-83.77497   22.599255   500 1   0   0.1
```

Comment: Can you upload the data frame that you created with `fortify()`?

Comment: @jazzuro - sure, its a good ~3500 lines though

Comment: Can you provide a minimal sample? As long as data reproduces the situation above, that will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. The reason why you ended up seeing the ggplot graphic is that you used `geom_line()`. geom_line() connects data points in order of the variable on the x axis. The reason why you see a polygon is that there are a bunch of vertical lines going up and down along the x-axis, and we perceive that area is filled, I think.

```
# geom_line() connects them in order of the variable on the x axis.
# I called your subsetted data mydata.

ggplot() +
geom_line(data = mydata, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), colour = "red")
```

[image]

Now I use `geom_path()` and see the route. One more thing. You want to have `color` outside of `aes()` in this case.

```
ggplot() +
geom_path(data = mydata, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), colour = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jazzurro! That's exactly what I was trying to do. Works a treat.

Comment: @vengefulsealion Pleasure to help. :)